# read values from query_string

Tags: c++

I want to read data from query_string.

eg:

```
username=kramsp&password=overfloww123
```

I want to read the values from the query_string

```
query= username=[data1] password=[data2]
//where data1, data2 are values

char *username = [data1]; // kramster
char *password = [data2]; // overfloww123
```

Comment: What you are talking about? Should that be SQL and not C++?

Comment: This query url GET method html,instead of querying the database//

Comment: you should tag your question with the appropriate things here. c++ is only one side of your question as it seems. I have no idea what lib you are using for accessing html or if you are asking how to split a string or what else.

Comment: I asked about c ++, how to enter data from the get method input. you mean to drop me ??

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Parsing a received string using C++ (with regex)

```
regex e("username=([[:w:]]+)&password=([[:w:]]+)");

string test = "username=kramsp&password=overfloww123";

smatch m;
regex_search(test, m, e);

if (m.size() > 2)
{
    const char *username = m[1].str().c_str();
    const char *password = m[2].str().c_str();

    cout << username << endl;
    cout << password << endl;
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64ef0a2923c09598)

Comment: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

Comment: I use the GNU GCC compiler compiler with IDE code block

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99b67fbab068d515

string test = "username=kramsp&password=overfloww123"; 
    
    int username_start = test.find('=') + 1;    
    int username_end = test.find('&') - 1;
    int len = username_end - username_start + 1; 
    
    const char* username = test.substr(username_start, len).c_str();
    
    const char* password = test.substr(username_end + 11).c_str();

    cout << username << endl;
    cout << password << endl;